# Is there any alterntive to wait3 to get rusage structure in shell scripting?

Tags: linux, time, solaris, rusage

I was trying to monitor the peak memory usage of a child process.time -v is an option,but it is not working in solaris.So is there any way to get details that are in rusage structure from shell scripting?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `/usr/bin/timex`

From [the `/usr/bin/timex` man page](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23823_01/html/816-5165/timex-1.html):

> The given command is executed; the elapsed time, user time and system
>   time spent in execution are reported in seconds. Optionally, process
>   accounting data for the command and all its children can be listed or
>   summarized, and total system activity during the execution interval
>   can be reported.
>
> ...
>
> -p List process accounting records for command and all its children. **This option works only if the process accounting software is installed.** Suboptions f, h, k, m, r, and t modify the data items
>   reported. The options are as follows:
>
> ...

Start with the man page for `acctadm` to get process accounting enabled.

Note that on Solaris, `getrusage()` and `wait3()` do not return memory usage statistics.  See the (somewhat dated) `getrusage()` source code at http://src.illumos.org/source/xref/illumos-gate/usr/src/uts/common/syscall/rusagesys.c and the `wait3()` source code at http://src.illumos.org/source/xref/illumos-gate/usr/src/lib/libbc/libc/sys/common/wait.c#158 (That's actually OpenSolaris source, which Oracle dropped support for, and it may not represent the current Solaris implementation, although a few tests on Solaris 11.2 show that the RSS data is in fact still zero.)

Also, from the [Solaris `getrusage()` man page](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23823_01/html/816-5168/getrusage-3c.html#REFMAN3Agetrusage-3c):

> The `ru_maxrss`, `ru_ixrss`, `ru_idrss`, and `ru_isrss` members of the
>   `rusage` structure are set to 0 in this implementation.

There are almost certainly other ways to get the data, such as `dtrace`.

Edit:

`dtrace` doesn't look to be much help, unfortunately.  Attempting to run this `dtrace` script with `dtrace -s memuse.d -c bash`

```
#!/usr/sbin/dtrace -s

#pragma D option quiet

profile:::profile-1001hz
/ pid == $target /
{
    @pct[ pid ] = max( curpsinfo->pr_pctmem );
}

dtrace:::END
{
    printa( "pct: %@u %a\n", @pct );
}
```

resulted in the following error message:

```
dtrace: failed to compile script memuse.d: line 8: translator does not define conversion for member: pr_pctmem
```

`dtrace` on Solaris doesn't appear to provide access to process memory usage.  In fact, the Solaris 11.2 `/usr/lib/dtrace/procfs.d` translator for `procfs` data has this comment in it:

```
/*
 * Translate from the kernel's proc_t structure to a proc(4) psinfo_t struct.
 * We do not provide support for pr_size, pr_rssize, pr_pctcpu, and pr_pctmem.
 * We also do not fill in pr_lwp (the lwpsinfo_t for the representative LWP)
 * because we do not have the ability to select and stop any representative.
 * Also, for the moment, pr_wstat, pr_time, and pr_ctime are not supported,
 * but these could be supported by DTrace in the future using subroutines.
 * Note that any member added to this translator should also be added to the
 * kthread_t-to-psinfo_t translator, below.
 */
```

Browsing the Illumos.org source code, searching for `ps_rssize`, indicates that the `procfs` data is computed only when needed, and not updated continually as the process runs.  (See http://src.illumos.org/source/search?q=pr_rssize&defs=&refs=&path=&hist=&project=illumos-gate)